Proxy between UNIX socket with socat
I used socal to create  a proxy server between 2 UNIX sockets: /var/a.sock , /var/b.sock
client -> /var/a.sock -> MY_COMMAND -> /var/b.sock -> MY_COMMAND -> /var/a.sock ->client.
The following commands works fine just for
client -> /var/a.sock -> /var/b.sock -> /var/a.sock -> client.
socat UNIX-LISTEN:/var/a.sock,fork 'UNIX-CONNECT:/var/b.sock
I need one more thing.
To replace AAAA with BBBB before send
How can I do that please ?

Replace in both directions or just one?

With socat 1 or socat 2?

Is it text being exchanged? Can that substitution be line-based (is it OK to delay the sending until a full line has been read) or not? If at message as received on one end by socat ends in A, AA. AAA, should it wait for more data to see if that ends up making up AAAA before changing to BBBB and sending? In the mean time, would it need to send what's before?

@StéphaneChazelas Thank you! I that substitution can be line by line (\r\n) . , I need the substitution for both or direction.

Could be something like:
socat unix-listen:/var/a.sock,fork \
      'system:"
         sed -u s/AAAA/BBBB/g |
           socat - unix-connect:/var/b.sock |
           sed -u s/AAAA/BBBB/g
       ",nofork'

The outer socat, upon each incoming connection on /var/a.sock forks a child in which as usual it establishes a two way communication between 2 addresses:

the accepted socket
the stdin and stdout of a child process that executes a shell to interpret the given shell code.

Without the nofork, what would be read from the socket would be written to a socketpair, the other side of which is the shell's stdin, while the shell's stdout would be that same socketpair and socat would read what comes from the other end and send it to the accepted socket.
With nofork, we cut the middle man, the shell's stdin and stdout are directly the accepted socket as an optimisation.
Here the shell code runs another socat command, which connects - aka STDIO, that is socat's own stdin and stdout with a connecting socket to /var/b.sock. That socat's stdin is pre-processed by sed, while its output is post-processed by another sed.
Beware -u¹ is not a standard option; if yours doesn't support it, you can switch to perl (perl -pe 'BEGIN{$| = 1}; s/AAAA/BBB/g').
If the data exchanged over those sockets is not line-based, you can use perl instead of sed and read by chunks of say up to 8KiB:
PERL_CODE='
  while (sysread(STDIN, $_, 8192)) {
    s/AAAA/BBBB/g;
    syswrite(STDOUT, $_);
  }
' socat unix-listen:/var/a.sock,fork \
        'system:{
           perl -e "$PERL_CODE" |
             socat - unix-connect:/var/b.sock |
             perl -e "$PERL_CODE"
         },nofork'

As long as data on a.sock doesn't come quicker than perl (and the recipient on b.sock) can handle it, and that it's not sent in batches bigger than 8KiB, it would be unlikely for a message to be cut in the middle of a AAAA.

¹ to prevent output buffering; though in the case of GNU sed, it also causes it to read its input one byte at a time, not harmful though unnecessary here.

That great! 1)how can I sure that sed wait for \r\n before it make the replacement? 2) Can I do that with nc (netcat) without socat ?

@Polo1990 1) that's what sed does, it's a line-based text utility 2) not sure why you would want to use nc when you can use socat, I gave up on nc (and its various, incompatible between each other and more or less bogus (at the time at least) implementations) a long time ago myself.

That great solution. But sometimes the second sed stuck , I think because the end of packet that /var/b.sock answer not ending with \r\n. Not each packet ending with breakline

@Polo1990, see edit for a non-line-based approach.

Thank you .....
